# Number of regions of the hypersphere partitioned by random hyperplanes

Tags: probability, geometry

Given N random hyperplanes and a D-dimensional sphere, how many regions is the sphere divided into by the hyperplanes?

I found the answer on the internet and it is $ C_{D}(N + 1) = C_{D}(N) + C_{D-1}(N) $. The explanation given is:

"To see now many chambers are sliced up by the new hyperplane, note that the new hyperplane is essentially a (D−1)-dimensional sphere. Each of the N old hyperplanes will intersect the new (D−1)-sphere along (D−2)-dimensional ”hyperlines”, and the number of chambers marked out on this (D − 1)-sphere is the number of chambers sliced up by the new hyperplane."

(chamber = region)

I do not understand the given explanation. In what way is the new hyperplane a (D-1) dimensional sphere? Is he/she talking about the intersection of the new hyperplane with the original D-dimensional sphere?

How is the recurrence relation derived?

Note that the hyperplanes are random so we ignore cases with zero probability such as when all the hyperplanes are concurrent.

Link to original:

http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/~velser/HW/hw1soln.pdf

Comment: critical here is that it is diameters not (general case) hyperplanes. This means (ignoring zero probability possibilities) they will always all intercept. this the intercept that is talked about. This is crucial for the argument presented in the offsite source. I do see how the argument is confusing though.

Comment: Can you please turn this into a full answer? You will get the bounty, it is expiring.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain below for $D=2$ and the explanation easily generalizes to higher dimensions.

For 2-dimensional sphere (centered at the origin), $n$ planes (through the origin) $H_1, \dots, H_n$ in general position intersect the sphere at $N$ great circles. Suppose these $n$ great circles (in general position) partition the sphere into $C_2(n)$ regions. Now we add another great circle $S_{n+1}$, and together they partition the sphere into $C_2(N+1)$ regions. The difference $C_2(n+1)-C_2(n)$ comes from the number of segments $S_{n+1}$ is partitioned into by $H_1, \dots, H_n$. Well, since $S_{n+1}$ is a $1$-dimensional sphere, this difference is thus $C_{1}(n)$.